# Find specific key-value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = {1: ['Serena', 'Williams', 38],2: ['Bradley', 'Cooper', 45],3: ['Wendy', 'Williams', 56],4: ['Bill', 'Gates', 72], 5: ['Normani', 'Kordei', 24]}
```

I have that dictionary with a list as values and I'm trying to access say the age (index 2 in the list) of key 3 when found. I tried this code

```
def record(num):
    my_dict = {1: ['Serena', 'Williams', 38],2: ['Bradley', 'Cooper', 45],3: ['Wendy', 'Williams', 56],
               4: ['Bill', 'Gates', 72], 5:['Normani', 'Kordei', 24]}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        fname = v[0]
        lname = v[1]
        age = v[2]
        if my_dict.get(num) is None:
            print('Not found')
        else:
            print(num, age, 'Found')

record(3) # Call function
```

I want something like if I call the function with record(3) I just get the age corresponding to that key like this:

```
3 56 Found
```

Currently I get:

```
3 38 Found
3 45 Found
3 56 Found
3 72 Found
3 24 Found
```

Comment: As a side observation, you can say `fname, lname, age = v` to distribute the contents of the three-element list `v` to individual variables; but you can also say `for k, (fname, lname, age) in my_dict.items():` to pick them up during iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a loop, you can just index directly into the dictionary.

```
def record(num):
    my_dict = {1: ['Serena', 'Williams', 38],2: ['Bradley', 'Cooper', 45],3: ['Wendy', 'Williams', 56],
               4: ['Bill', 'Gates', 72], 5:['Normani', 'Kordei', 24]}
    if num in my_dict:
        print(num, my_dict[num][2], "Found")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

or use try-except to handle the "not found" case (which some may argue is more "Pythonic"):

```
def record(num):
    my_dict = {1: ['Serena', 'Williams', 38],2: ['Bradley', 'Cooper', 45],3: ['Wendy', 'Williams', 56],
               4: ['Bill', 'Gates', 72], 5:['Normani', 'Kordei', 24]}
    try:
        print(num, my_dict[num][2], "Found")
    except KeyError:
        print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [SuperStormer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453325/4475468), you should be directly accessing the record for `num` by invoking the key on the directory. However using the iteration process you do, the correct item to check is whether `k` matches the desired key `num`.

Note this approach is ***not recommended*** - this is just a clean-up of your method:

```py
my_dict = {1: ['Serena', 'Williams', 38], 2: ['Bradley', 'Cooper', 45],
        3: ['Wendy', 'Williams', 56], 4: ['Bill', 'Gates', 72], 
        5:['Normani', 'Kordei', 24]}

def record(num):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        fname, lname, age = v
        if k == num:
            print(num, age, 'Found')
            return
    print (num, "Not found")  

for a in range(7):  # Call function repeatedly to check cases
    record(a)
```

The output from the seven calls to `record` above is:

```
0 Not found
1 38 Found
2 45 Found
3 56 Found
4 72 Found
5 24 Found
6 Not found
```

Comment: Thanks guys! How would I check if the age in the list is greater than say 40? Like 'if num in my_dict > 40, I know the two types won't work (list and int) so how would I make them the same type?

Comment: I suggest you accept SuperStormer's answer (click the checkmark). As you currently have the dict set up, looking for age above some threshold is a case where you might want to loop through all records. So you can adapt the above to collect which records meet your desired properties and return the key list at the end. If you want that, try it, and ask a different question if you have problems..